# ASP.NET MVC5 Googlemaps

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

Trying to get map from googleapi, return Network error in firebug:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:15618/Home/https//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY"
```

Source code in Contact view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=MY_KEY"></script>
```

> @section Scripts{
>
> ```
>     function initialize() {
>
>         var canvas = $("#map_canvas");
>
>         var latitude = 30.3296604;
>         var longitude = -97.8743174;
>
>         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
>         var options = {
>             zoom: 8,
>             center: latlng,
>             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>         };
>         var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas[0], options);
>
>         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>             position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
>             map: map
>         });
>     }
>
>     $(function () { //Same as $(document).ready()
>         initialize();
>     });
>
> </script> }
> ```

I have tried to use CDN in BundleConfig.cs, without result

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; //force optimization while debugging

var jquery = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyALDo0MgNC8vRSNN3It38Yo9L_g8_8GoqM").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js");
bundles.Add(jquery);
```

Comment: I've no experience with ASP.NET, but... This `@section Scripts{` has closing `</script>` and there is no opening tag `<script>`. This network error is strange. Did you try to move link of google api to `@section Scripts{` part?

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Bad copy/past, "<script type="text/javascript">" is missing after "@section Scripts{"
I have try this code in an html page, with the same result.
It look like a bug in ASP.NET MVC routing or Bundle

Comment: Your script source is missing a `:`. `https//` should be `https://` Voting to close as typographical error.

Comment: Thanks MikeSmithDev, that resolve my problem (I'm getting older) :)

Comment: Live demo with source code: [link](http://www.jow-alva.net/NorthWind/Home/Contact)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution.

Live Demo : ***http://jsbin.com/ruyaxidi/1***

```
Address : <input id="Address" /><button id="ViewMap">Show Map</button>
<div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; top:30px ;position:relative"></div>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
      document.getElementById("ViewMap").onclick = function f() {
            initialize();
        }

      </script>

    <script>
    var geocoder;
    var map;
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
        codeAddress();
    }
    function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('Address').value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                if (marker)
                    marker.setMap(null);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    draggable: true
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function () {
                    document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
                    document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
                });
                document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.getPosition().lat();
                document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.getPosition().lng();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("Address").placeholder = ("Map not set!");
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```